# Adding custom files to war file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I'm trying to add additional files to a war file (VERSION and REVISION file) using RoR/warbler. The VERSION file would be similar to what capistrano creates so each file would need to be created during the war creation. Does anyone have any suggestions? I was looking at creating custom warbler FEATURES but can't find any documentation about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is what I did:

Really most of the magic was done in a rake task:

```
require 'warbler'
Warbler::Task.new

# other tasks

desc "Put the revision that was packaged into RAILS_ROOT/VERSION"
task :write_revision do
  `cd #{Rails.root} && git rev-parse HEAD > REVISION`
end

task :war => :write_revision
```

next I modified the warble.rb config to include the additional files in the war file:

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
   # ...
   config.includes = FileList["REVISION"]
   # ...
end
```

So now whenever I run `bundle exec rake war` or another task that calls `war` it will add a REVISION file. The only non-issue is that you can't use the `warble` command.